# How to not split select list by content type

Tags: forms

This is about the regular `select` widget that you can choose in the `Manage form display` page.

If this widget is linked to an `entity_reference` field allowing several bundles to be selected; then you end up with an `#options` populated as follow:

```
_none -> "None"
Bundle label 1 ->
  id1 -> "label of ID 1"
  id3 -> "label of ID 3"
  id4 -> "label of ID 4"
Bundle label 1 ->
  id5 -> "label of ID 5"
  id6 -> "label of ID 6"
```

I would like to have

```
_none -> "None"
id1 -> "label of ID 1"
id3 -> "label of ID 3"
id4 -> "label of ID 4"
id5 -> "label of ID 5"
id6 -> "label of ID 6"
```

Is there any option to change? or should I hook something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be nice if this were optional, but ...

You will have to write a `hook_form_alter` or similar to rewrite/reorganize the options in the field: They're organized in logically obvious subarrays matching what you see on screen. You can "flatten" them into a single array and re-order the options as you please.

Comment: Thanks you, I accepted your answer because you explain that there are no simple way except flattening manually. Note that using a view to populate the options doesn't solve the problem... [maybe you can update your answer for this point]